# PHP how to check if display errors

Tags: php, if-statement

Im looking forward making conditional that checks if display_errors in php (on any level, simply yes or no) is on or off in if statement.

Is there any way to do this?

edit:
this question is about checking status of display_errors but not how to set it on and off. its something diffrent.

Comment: `ini_get` function

Comment: show some code you tested...

Comment: @u_mulder you may add this as answer as this is what I was looking for...

Comment: `var_dump(ini_get('display_errors'));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP Errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: One of the examples shown in one of the answers in the link above, shows how to check if errors was set... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34721287/2506641

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo 'display_errors = ' . ini_get('display_errors') . "\n";
```

Output:

> display_errors = 1

Or

> display_errors = 0

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php

Comment: Note: to be clear, the 0 and 1 output were numeric strings."0" and "1". var_dump (ini_get ('directive')) is less ambiguous and might help you decide how to test. Also, 0 and 1 understates the galaxy of ini_get return values if a directive was set in runtime. eg. `ini_set('display_errors', 'True');` or even `'yEs', 'oN', 'tRuE'`